# Rselenium connection times out before connecting to server after updating Chrome

Tags: r, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have used RSelenium to scrape webpages without any issue for over a year including updating Chrome regularly. Today I updated Chrome to its latest version (89.0.4389.82). After the update, RSelenium can't connect to the server and times out. Here is the error message:

```
Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: xxx, os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Could not open chrome browser.
```

I also don't know why it says driver version unknown. I followed the guides on other simular questions and updated chromedriver to version 89.0.4389.23.

Here is the code that used to work before updating chrome:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="87.0.4280.88", port = 4568)
```

Here is what I'm working with now which results in an error:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="89.0.4389.23", port = as.integer(4568))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this thanks to [this](https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/issues/25) info I found. You can visit the link for more detailed information.

rsDriver has a boolean argument check that is TRUE by default. Its official description:

> If TRUE check the versions of selenium available and the versions of
> associated drivers (chromever, geckover, phantomver, iedrver). If new
> versions are available they will be downloaded.

This downloads both ***chromedriver_mac64.zip*** and ***chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip***. The chromedriver installed from the m1 file on Macs. What I did to fix the problem was go to

> ~/Library/Application Support/binman_chromedriver/mac64/89.0.4389.23

and then delete the m1 file and ***chromedriver***. Then unzip ***chromedriver_mac64.zip*** to get the correct chromedriver. Go back to R and run rsDriver with the argument check set to false:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="87.0.4280.88", port = 4568, check = FALSE)
```

This made it work for me